# How to obtain temporary authorization code in Slack API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, slack, slack-api

I am referring https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth#flow to obtain access token in PostMan.

Also, I have downloaded repo of slack api from https://github.com/lonelyclaud/slack-api-postman

Below command returns status 200, but no authorization code.

```js
curl -X GET \
  'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=9XX331444993.996747590037&scope=team%3Aread+users%3Aread%20' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f2dc4c20-5b7d-4ed2-b71f-08ecad81fd8c' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Can someone explain how to obtain code, which in turn will be used to obtain token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer, here is the link to obtain the auth token using Postman [Create a Slack app and authenticate with Postman](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/slack-apps-and-postman)